# Assigning each character within a String a new set of characters

Tags: java, android, string, char, encode

I am attempting to add a feature into my Android application that allows a user to enter some text, let's say *"testing"* and when they click a button the program reads the text, converts it to a string, then assigns each character a new value and displays those values on the screen. For example with *"testing"*, the program will change this to *"t e s t i n g"*. Then it needs to change the value of the characters, so 
*"t e s t i n g"*
 could become *"**t**a **e**a **s**a **t**a **i**a **n**a **g**a"*.

So essentially I need to:

1. Break down to original *string* into its individual *characters*.
2. Change the value of all of the individual *characters* to a new value *(Example: a = abc, b = bcd, c = wxy)*
3. Display the new values in a *TextView* on the screen.

Feel free to ask in a comment if you need more information about my problem. All help is greatly appreciated!!

Edit: 
A small example of the code I will be actually using is stated below

> "a" = "o9Q5QD8gT8"
>   "A" = "x5h10vc4jd15"
>   "1" = "S7J11IH4yK16"

I have codes similar to the ones shown for all letters (a-z) capital and lowercase, all numbers (0-9), and all extra characters

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I'm working with android and the all of this needs to happen inside the OnClick of a button.

Comment: You have an algorithm already. Do you encounter any difficulties when coding it? If so, please include what you have done in the question.

Comment: How did you tried to implement it what are the errors you got?

Comment: still dont see your code

Comment: I have attempted simply using "string.replace", however this didn't work for a number of reasons.. I have also tried converting the string to a charArray however I do not no much about arrays and couldn't find any code that worked well enough to pass eclipse's error check

Comment: Use the Java StringBuilder class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Translator {

    private static final Map<Character, String> translations = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        translations.put('a', "o9Q5QD8gT8");
        translations.put('A', "x5h10vc4jd15");
        translations.put('1', "S7J11IH4yK16");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(translate("abcABC123"));
    }

    private static String translate(final String input) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(translate(c));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String translate(final char c) {
        String translation = translations.get(c);
        if (translation == null) {
            translation = Character.toString(c);
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
o9Q5QD8gT8bcx5h10vc4jd15BCS7J11IH4yK1623
```

This solution iterates over the characters of the input String and looks them up in a static Map. If the character occurs as a key in the Map the associated value is used as translation value, otherwise the original character is used. A StringBuider is used to append the translation values in order.

Note that using a static Map like this is usually not a good long-term solution. The keys and values in the Map likely need to be managed somewhere, e.g. in a database or properties file.

EDIT: Modified version which reads from a properties file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Translator {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME = "translations.properties";
    private final Properties translations = new Properties();

    public Translator() {
        // Below is the try-with-resources syntax, available since 1.7
        // See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
        try (InputStream input = Translator.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME)) {
            System.out.println(input);
            translations.load(input);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Translator translator = new Translator();
        System.out.println(translator.translate("abcABC123"));
    }

    private String translate(final String input) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(translate(c));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String translate(final char c) {
        String translation = translations.getProperty(String.valueOf(c));
        if (translation == null) {
            translation = Character.toString(c);
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

Create a file 'translations.properties' with the contents below and make sure it is on the classpath.

```
a=o9Q5QD8gT8
A=x5h10vc4jd15
1=S7J11IH4yK16
```

Comment: Thanks @AdriaanKoster !! This works perfectly! You suggested that I should put my keys and values in a separate place, and I agree because I will have 95 different pairs of characters and their new values.. Do you have a suggestion on where / how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

```
    Hi i think this may work.


       class Stack {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String character="testing";
    for(int i=0;i<character.length();i++)
    {
        char a=character.charAt(i);
        switch(a)
        {
        case 't':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        case 'e':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        case 's':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        case 'i':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        case 'n':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        case 'g':System.out.print(a+"a");
        break;
        default:System.out.print("OUT");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is not a correct or elegant solution IMO because: it uses a switch statement, uses System.out.print and outputs "OUT" for any unrecognized characters.